# C# HttpClient Abruptly stops download

Tags: c#

I have this C# Script that is supposed to download a zip archive from GitHub, unpack it and put it in a specific folder:

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath("runtime");@"https://github.com/BlackBirdTV/tank/releases/latest/download/runtime.zip?raw=true";
    ConsoleUtilities.UpdateProgress("Downloading Runtime...", 0);
    var request = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
    var buffer = new byte[(int)bufferSize];
    var totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = await request.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        totalBytesRead += bytes;
        ConsoleUtilities.UpdateProgress($"Downloading Runtime... ({totalBytesRead} of {bufferSize} bytes read) ", (int)(totalBytesRead / bufferSize * 100));
    }
}
Decompress(buffer, filePath);
```

When I now run this, the download starts and it seems like it finishes, yet at a sporadic place it just stops. Somehow, It downloads the bytes as my Console shows, but they are zeroed out. It seems like either my computer receives zeros (which I doubt) or the bytes don't get written to the buffer.

[image: Hex from C# Downloaded file]

Weirdly enough, downloading the file over the browser works just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Well for starters *never* call result on a Task. The correct way to wait for a task result is async/await.

Comment: Also, never manually Dispose a disposable, use a using block.

Comment: @NickBailey I actually realized that after posting and edited it, imma edit my question

Comment: why you are not awaiting GetStreamAsync?

Comment: why not write the code synchronously and deal with asynchronicity at a higher level?

Comment: I'm sorry If I do many mistakes, Http Requests are just completely new terretory for me

Comment: @BlackBird then I recommend writing your code synchronously. It will make everything much more clear and probably solve your problem

Comment: @BlackBird After these async changes, are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: Each iteration of your `while` loop is overwriting your buffer, and you are not accumulating the data anywhere.  So your last iteration doesn't completely fill the buffer and all you're left with is whatever data you got in the last iteration.

Comment: @mxmissle nope, still just zeroed bytes

Comment: @KirkWoll could you please elaborate further? Having read the documentation and assuming that Microsoft is right, my code should work fine.

Comment: @BlackBird I've provided an answer with a better solution, but as far as understanding why this isn't working, please think about what the `ReadAsync` method is doing.  It is getting a chunk of data and filling _the same buffer_ on each iteration.  If the `while` loop executes 5 times, you will have overwritten the buffer 4 times without having done anything with that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I state in the comments, your problem is that each iteration of your while loop is overwriting your buffer, and you are not accumulating the data anywhere. So your last iteration doesn't completely fill the buffer and all you're left with is whatever data you got in the last iteration.

You could fix that bug by storing the accumulated buffer somewhere, but a far better solution is to not fuss with buffers and such and just use the built-in `CopyToAsync` method of `Stream`:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://github.com/BlackBirdTV/tank/releases/latest/download/runtime.zip?raw=true");
using var file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\runtime.zip", FileMode.Create);
await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
```

Here I'm saving it to a local file at `c:\temp\runtime.zip`, but obviously change that to suit your needs.  I suppose you're avoiding this method so you can track progress, which is fair enough.  So if that's really important to you, read on for a fix to your original solution.

---

For completeness, here's your original code fixed up to work by writing the buffer to a `FileStream`:

```
var bufferSize = 1024 * 10;
var url = @"https://github.com/BlackBirdTV/tank/releases/latest/download/runtime.zip?raw=true";

using var client = new HttpClient();
using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
using var file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\runtime.zip", FileMode.Create);

var filePath = Path.GetFullPath("runtime"); 
var request = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
var buffer = new byte[(int)bufferSize];
var totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytes = 0;
while ((bytes = await request.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    await file.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytes);
    totalBytesRead += bytes;
    ConsoleUtilities.UpdateProgress($"Downloading Runtime... ({totalBytesRead} of {bufferSize} bytes read) ", (int)(totalBytesRead / bufferSize * 100));
}
```